# UIImagePickerController gives me a black preview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UIImagePickerController` to take image. I'm using the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController* UIPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
UIPicker.delegate = self;
UIPicker.sourceType= UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[UIPicker setCameraCaptureMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto];
UIPicker.allowsEditing=NO;
[self presentModalViewController:UIPicker animated:YES];
[UIPicker release];
```

The problem is that randomly I am getting the preview as a black screen, if it happens once then it never restores until we kill and restart the application.

I am getting correct image from `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` but I have this problem with preview when `UIImagePickerController` has camera as source type.

Answer (score 0):

If it randomly happens, I doubt it's a memory issue. The image from UIImagePickerController is quite a big one. If you manage to manipulate the image somehow, your memory might not be able to support that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem with the camera preview tonight, and the root cause of the problem was … completely unrelated code in the app delegate that modified UI on a background queue.

Apparently, it doesn't take much to unsettle the fragile internal variables that AVFoundation relies on.

Once I eliminated the calls to UI code from background queues, the camera preview became fast and reliable.

This article ( http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/02/uiview-background-queue-debugging/ ) was very helpful in tracking down where the UI was being modified from a background queue.

I also recommend that you check out the answer to this question ( [iOS 7 UIImagePickerController has black preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081701/ios-7-uiimagepickercontroller-has-black-preview?lq=1) )