# multiple pictures with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

i've been searching around the web but couldn't find an answer.
basically i wanna take two photos one right after the other.
i'm using UIImagePickerController to show a picker and implementing didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. 
when it gets called i'm checking my count so that if its one, i implement a block and pass it to dismissViewControllerAnimated like this:

```
if(1 == count) {
    void (^simpleBlock)(void);
    simpleBlock = ^{
        [self useCamera];
    };

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:simpleBlock];
}
```

it all seems to work fine, and even the useCamera method is called.
**the problem** is that the second time the picker shows i see all of its controls but i don't see on the screen the image from the camera.

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: is it still allocated properly the second time?

Comment: yes, i'm checking my picker against nil

Answer (score 2):

i managed to work it out with replacing the call to useCamera with:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(useCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
```

i think my question has some relation to: [iOS 7 UIImagePickerController has black preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081701/ios-7-uiimagepickercontroller-has-black-preview)
since the delay fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For you to save time. You can use available library out there. These are my good choices. [CTAssetsPickerController](https://github.com/chiunam/CTAssetsPickerController) [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController/tree/master/Classes/ELCImagePicker)

Comment: thanks, i think i looked at those libs already, they let you multiple choose photos from your photo library and not multiple 'take picture'

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePickerController helps to access the default camera app in iOS.

It will allow only limited functionalities like take picture/video, photo album.